# How to set Company as default based on user login in Acumatica Generic Inquiry

Tags: mysql, database, generics, acumatica

I am creating a generic inquiry in Acumatica and I can't set the Company parameter default to user login.

I have maintained the parameter "Company" in the Generic Inquiry. Now I want the default company filled up based on user current login. What will be the condition to auto populate it based on user log in? Thank you!

[Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5ftD.png)

[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCgNj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could get the current branch selected in a read-only filter. From there you could get the company from joining the branch table. Branch's OrganizationID is the company of the selected branch.

https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2018/11/generic-inquiry-with-filtering-by-current-branch.html